# Image with white-on-purple text not recognized by Tesseract, even converted to B&W

Tags: python, tesseract

I am Using the Below code . But tesseract cant even ocr from this simple image.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
image_file = Image.open("question.png")

image_file = image_file.convert('1') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('question.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_file, lang = 'eng',config='-psm 6')
print(text)
```

*Note:
[1.] Tried to turn Pic into black and white
[2.] Used psm*

**QUESTION: How to OCR the given image correctly?**

[image: Question.png]

***Updates:***

I used this code now:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image_file = Image.open('purple.png')

image_file = image_file.convert('L') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('question.png')
image_file = Image.open('question.png') #without this line also the output is same
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_file, lang = 'eng',config='-psm 6')
print(text)
```

Output:

[image]

**Please help me why it doesn't work.**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to OCR the given image correctly.

Comment: Please update your question to show what happens when you run your code.

Comment: If the conversion happens successfully, you might show and include the black-and-white image, and leave the original out entirely -- one part of building a [mcve] is removing any/all unnecessary elements, after all.

Comment: Please do not copy images of text.

Answer (score 4):

With `image.convert('-1')` you get this image

[image]

It's a picture with a lot of *noise*, so Tesseract will fail with it.

I suggest you to convert it to a better grayscaled image with `image_file.convert('L')` (for more information about `'1'` mode and `'L'` mode take a look at the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)). With `'L'` mode you will get

[image]

With this image Tesseract is perfectly able to recognize the text

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image_file = Image.open('purple.png')

image_file = image_file.convert('L') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('question.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_file, lang = 'eng',config='-psm 6')
print(text)
```

Tesseract output:

> which of these elements Is a gas In Its 
>   standard state?

Comment: Thanks For this answer But I am still not able to get the output. I'll update the new details in question itself.